# Plot multiple coordinates on white images on Matlab or Python

Tags: python, matlab, plot, coordinates

I have multiple .txt files like this

```
Detected 4
block 0: sig: 1 x: 112 y: 96 
block 1: sig: 1 x: 15 y: 110
block 2: sig: 1 x: 112 y: 131 
block 3: sig: 1 x: 252 y: 80
```

I want to import the x,y coordinates and plot them on a white 240*300 jpeg image that I don't have.( This means I have to create the white image ) I have more than 1000 txt files and want to make the plotted images for each txt file.
It would be great if I could change the size of the plots easily.

Add

These multiple txt files come form an original txt file like this.

```
Detected 3
  block 0: sig: 1 x: 31 y: 65 width: 62 height: 51 index: 12 age: 58
  block 1: sig: 1 x: 187 y: 50 width: 62 height: 6 index: 34 age: 0
  block 2: sig: 1 x: 283 y: 105 width: 22 height: 3 index: 32 age: 5
Detected 3
  block 0: sig: 1 x: 24 y: 81 width: 48 height: 25 index: 12 age: 59
  block 1: sig: 1 x: 152 y: 62 width: 68 height: 12 index: 34 age: 1
  block 2: sig: 1 x: 252 y: 80 width: 60 height: 2 index: 32 age: 6
Detected 4
  block 0: sig: 1 x: 112 y: 96 width: 60 height: 12 index: 34 age: 2
  block 1: sig: 1 x: 15 y: 110 width: 26 height: 11 index: 12 age: 60
  block 2: sig: 1 x: 112 y: 131 width: 36 height: 5 index: 38 age: 0
  block 3: sig: 1 x: 252 y: 80 width: 60 height: 2 index: 32 age: 7
  .
  .
  .
```

I just split it so that it makes it easier to reference them later but I still have this original file.

Comment: 1. process your data to get (x,y) points, 2. create a zero array for your image and set the corresponding (x,y) pixels to 1, 3. read about `imshow`  in MATLAB or `matplotlib.pyplot.imshow` (or `PIL.Image.fromarray`) in python, 4. plot and profit. Your question is too broad as-is; we won't write code for you from scratch. Start implementing the step-by-step straightforward procedure, and let us know if you need help with specific parts of your code.

Comment: @AndrasDeak  Thank you for suggesting the way! I'm a beginner and didn't know what to start off so you helped me a lot! If I get stuck in writing codes along your idea, I might ask you a question! Thank you :)

Comment: I'm glad I could help :) Good luck with it!